# Accessing POST request data from CGIHTTPServer (python)

Tags: php, python, cgi, webserver, cgihttprequesthandler

I have a very simple CGI webserver running using python CGIHTTPServer class.
This class spawns and executes a cgi-php script.
If the webpage sends POST request, how can I access the POST request data in the php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say your Python process "spawns and executes" a cgi-php script, I believe what you mean is "it calls my PHP script by executing the PHP CLI executable, passing it the name of my script."

Using the PHP CLI executable, HTTP-specific superglobals and environment values will not be set automatically.  You would have to read in all HTTP request headers and GET/POST data in your Python server process, and then set them in the environment used by your PHP script.

The whole experiment sounds interesting, but this is what mod_php does already.

Comment: Yes you are quite right and I did not clarify in my question. I know that I'll have to set the POST data in global variables for the cgi script. However, my problem is I don't know which routine receives that data in the python CGIHTTPServer. There is a run_cgi() routine that listens for additional data. However that data is discarded. So I am confused.

Comment: Have a look at the `BaseHTTPServer` class...it's an ancestor class of `CGIHTTPServer`.  Here's the reference:  http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler